# Add categories to local storage in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I need to add custom categories to all accounts and local storages(pst).

Usually that code works fine:

```
Outlook.Stores stores = Application.Session.Stores;
foreach(Outlook.Store store in stores){
    store.Categories.add(someName, someColor);
}
```

But if I set storage like default datafile, categories don't add to that storage.

**UPD** In other words, if I set `.ost` like default it's work correct. But if I set `.pst` like default, category is'nt added (in others all fine).

[image]

Comment: What does "But if I set storage like default datafile" mean?

Comment: add more info to question.

Comment: How do you check if the Categories were added? Categories are stored in a hidden message in the Calendar  with PR_MESSAGE_CLASS == "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList", PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM property. You can see the data in OutlookSpy - go to the Calendar folder of the problematic store, click IMAPIFolder button, go to the "Associated Contents" tab, double click on the "IPM.Configuration.CategoryList" message.

Comment: Check it. PR_ROAMING_XMLSTREAM almost empty. (In ".ost", that property have needful categories)

Comment: I can only suggest using Redemption - it exposes the RDOCategories object on the store level - http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdocategories.htm